# Sources of the difference in using "года" and "лет"

Tags: грамматика, множественное-число

I'm a native speaker, but I can't explain. Why we use "года" and "лет" in different situations? For example, when we talk about age of people. Can you explain sources of using these words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В формах единственного числа слова *год* и *лето* очевидно употребляются в разных значениях. Но во множественном числе имеет место "конкуренция" между ними. Например,

> Дожив без цели, без трудов до двадцати пяти *годов*
>   И правда то, что в наши *лета* довольно скучен высший тон

В итоге получилось так, что форма "*лет*" стала основной формой родительного падежа мн.ч. для слова "год", хотя форма "*годов*" все еще допустима, если используется не с количественными числительными (см. "Грамматический словарь" Зализняка).

В принципе, такое иногда случается, что некоторые грамматические формы одного слова заменяются формами другого, близкого по смыслу. В качестве примера из английского языка глагол *to go* и его форма прошедшего времени *went* (фактически же это форма глагола *to wend*).

Comment: Лето translate like summer. We have not Именительный падеж for this word.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim Both "лето" and "лета́" are Nominative. You probably mean that "лето"="summer" sing. and ""лета́""="age" pl. are considered to be _different_ words in modern language. But they are still naturally related to each other.

Comment: @Matt На самом деле меня больше интересует ответ на вопрос почему в русском языке происходит чередование 1 год, ..., 4 года, 5 лет, .... Такой эффект возникает в любом десятке кроме 2.

Comment: @NikolaiKarpov Тогда так и надо было спрашивать ;-) Посмотрите [тут](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/special-treatment-for-plural-forms-depending-on-number-of-objects-where-does-i), [тут](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/406/the-origin-of-complex-plural-forms) и [тут](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/75/are-there-analogous-words-for-words-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5-for-three-and-more).